# How run own instance of LanguageTool 4.0 on Specific IP Address

Tags: java, languagetool

I want to run my own instance of LanguageTool on my server IP Address other than the Localhost:8081

But from some document, I have read that

> -Server mode: by default, the server only binds to localhost now

I just want to ask that how to run LT Server on specific IP along Port from this command.

```
java -cp languagetool-server.jar org.languagetool.server.HTTPServer --port 8081
```

Or tell me how to add IP address on above command to start the server on specific IP Address & Port.

Comment: Are you trying to start the LT on a remote machine? Can you explain it better? The nature of a server is it to run in the machine it is. You can't run a server that is in a machine A with the IP of a machine B that doesn't have the Server on it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos This URL will help you more understanding, http://wiki.languagetool.org/http-server    From Here: -You can test the server by calling this URL in your browser:
http://localhost:8081/v2/check?language=en-US&text=my+text

Comment: The purpose of this site is to have all necessary info on your question without external sources. So, add the relevant info on your question. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have got the solution.

just by adding the **--public** in the command allows LanguageTool server to access from the server Local IP Address than the Localhost:8081

Means if I run the command

```
java -cp languagetool-server.jar org.languagetool.server.HTTPServer --port 8081 --public
```

I can access the LT Server from the IP address that was only with localhost earlier.

```
http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8081/v2/check?language=en-US&text=my+text
```

Comment: So, what you were trying to do was to use the server IP instead of the localhost domain name. Your question leads to the understanding that you want to call it from a specific IP which means any IP. You may want to edit your question to add that information. Though, good that you find a solution.